# webview cannot enter text in android 2.3.6

Tags: android, webview

i am loading the following URL in to a WebView:

http://crm.unitask-inc.com/dotproject/DP/

in android v4.x it works fine.

in android 2.x when i try to enter text in to the text fields.
the keyboard shows up and i can heare the ticking while typing.
i but no text is entered to the text box.

I tried to set the focus of the WebView, but it didn't help.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot

Avi

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Answer (score 0):

It's not problem with Android 2.x. It's problem with "Https" url in android 2.x

Comment: bu it isn't an HTTPS url.
it's an HTTP urs

Comment: Basically webview in android has a bug

Comment: Can you please explain what is the bug?
It's a bit strange because in Version 4.x it works correctly

Answer (score 0):

May this help you....

[Android soft keyboard hides inputs from CordovaWebView when in fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17194769/android-soft-keyboard-hides-inputs-from-cordovawebview-when-in-fullscreen)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a bug with `WebView` for your issue. I'm currently using it with 2.2 to 4.3 versions of devices and I never had a problem as you described.

You can test it with an url like google to define your problem again. As I see problem comes from your page at url http://crm.unitask-inc.com/dotproject/DP/

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    WebView webView = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(webView);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
}
```

**BTW,** I've tested google's url on 2.2 Nexus One (Emulator) Device. Didn't have any problem there.

**Edit:** I've tested [your url](http://crm.unitask-inc.com/dotproject/DP/) on 2.2 Nexus One (Emulator) Device and 4.3 Galaxy Nexus device. They only showed 3 blinking dot on a blue page. Never saw the entry page.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

For more info refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41009234/6521116).